# Accessing a 3rd party REST service from sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server

I'm trying to integrate a pretty simple REST service from Sharepoint.  This service is hosted on a different domain, and I just need to do a GET against it to pull a JSON array of data on page load from one of my content pages.

Obviously, a regular Ajax call fails b/c of same-origin, and so I was hoping there was a native way to proxy or host third party data from inside sharepoint so that my clientside script can get at it.

I did a lot of searching online, and found a /_api/SP.WebProxy.invoke endpoint which allegedly works in 2013, but that doesn't help me much if it doesn't exist in 2010 (I tried using it, and got a 404 error).  It's also not very well documented, so I may have the wrong knobs set in my json POST to it.

Comment: You are correct. It doesn't exist in 2010. You would need to write your own proxy. You could do this either as a custom WCF service or your code could be within the page via code behind. If I were doing this, I would likely choose the WCF method.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I'll upvote your question once I am able. I've used all my votes for a 24 hr period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. It doesn't exist in 2010. You would need to write your own proxy. You could do this either as [a custom WCF service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff521584%28v=office.14%29.aspx) or your code could be within the page via code behind. If I were doing this, I would likely choose the WCF method.

Answer (score 0):

Normal WCF Services don't have cross browser capability. JSONP has been introduced for that. [This is a blog which explains how JSONP is used to make a cross domain call](http://tech.just4sharing.com/Pages/tech/WCF-with-JSON.aspx)

Comment: yeah, if I write a service and add it to my Sharepoint instance, I don't need to worry about that.  I was trying to figure out if Sharepoint already had a built-in proxy.